# accessing same element from two lists at a time

Tags: python, list

In Python if I have 2 lists of the same length and want to pass corresponding elements to a function, how do I do this? For example I want item n from list 1 and item n from list 2 to be passed to someFunction().
In pseudocode and with arrays it would look like this

```
arr1;
arr2;
for(int i=0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    val = someFunction(arr1[i], arr2[i])
```

Comment: `for i, j in zip(lst1, lst2): func(i,j)`

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you would rewrite your example using proper Python code:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [4, 5, 6]
for a, b in zip(arr1, arr2):
    val = some_function(a, b)
```

Comment: Will `a` and `b` always have the same value?

Comment: `a` and `b` are the actual values in the two arrays, not indices.

Comment: @Celeritas ```a``` and ```b``` will have the same index number - always. [```itertools.starmap```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) used with ```zip``` may also interest you.

Comment: @Celeritas They will have the same relative positions but only the same values if the values at that same relative position are the same.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower, it might be worth noting that your example is Python 3  and if the OP is using Python 2 they'll have to change your lambda into a proper `def` (or `from __future__ import print_function`).

Comment: @Duncan It has been fixed with some generic printing code. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: May I suggest to make a comment or something on `do_magic`? I assume it's an example function but this is unclear as it's missing the `()` and `lambda` is not exactly a trivial concept and I'm assuming it means the same thing in Python as it does in Java. e.g. at first I was confused if `do_magic` was necessary for the iteration of the two lists.

Comment: @Celeritas Hopefully, the corrected code is less confusing now.

Answer (score 2):

If I have two lists:

```
arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
arr2 = ['1', '2', '3']
```

And I want to loop over them so they are accessing the element at the same index, I would do this:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    val = someFunction(arr1[i], arr2[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

In python it would be something like this:

```
for x in xrange(len(arr1)):
    val = someFunction(arr1[x], arr2[x])
```